# vector of strings - variable update

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I created a function that takes a string and turns it into a vector of strings and returns this vector, without spaces and operators separated, but in creating realized that the variable i will not update their values, after the while, and repeats the insertion, because the i is not updated?
Obs: It is not allowed to use existing methods, for example, Split...

```
def vector(exp):
    Exp = []
    for i in range(len(exp)):        
        if exp[i] != ' ' and exp[i] != '+':
            j = i
            while exp[i] != ' ' and exp[i] != '+' and i < len(exp):            
                i += 1
            valor = exp[j:i]
            Exp.append(valor)      
        elif exp[i] == '+':
            Exp.append(exp[i])           
    return Exp

exp = '3563 + 36+ 27'
print(vector(exp))
```

Comment: why not do `exp.split(' ')`? it will return `['3563', '+', '36', '+', '27']`

Comment: It is not allowed, the idea is not to use existing methods for working with strings

Comment: that's an important detail that you should add to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues, as you are already discovering, for loops and while loops don't always mix with the desired effect. You can avoid some of those issues by using a while loop on your outer loop.

Also in your inner while loop you need to move up the `i < len(exp)` check. If you don't the `exp[i] != ' '` will get evaluated with an i value that is too large and you will get an index out of range error.

By moving the `i < len(exp)` to the front, this will fail and prevent the rest of the while condition from being evaluated.

Like so:

```
def vector(exp):
    Exp = []
    i=1
    while i < len(exp):
        if exp[i] != ' ' and exp[i] != '+':
            j = i
            while i < len(exp) and exp[i] != ' ' and exp[i] != '+':            
                i += 1
            valor = exp[j:i]
            Exp.append(valor)      
        elif exp[i] == '+':
            Exp.append(exp[i])
        i += 1
    return Exp

exp = '3563 + 36 + 27'
print(vector(exp))
```